# Export all files name in all disks powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have to export the names of all the files on all the disks on some machines.
At the moment I have this command line.

```
$date = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy")
gci . *.* -rec | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer} | Select-Object FullName | Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME'_'FilesAudit'_'$date.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The problem is that if I execute this code, it only extracts the information from the disk I am running and not from the other disks.

I don't know how I can get the information from the other disks, and as an extra problem, each machine has different disks, for example, C: + D: or C: + E: or C: + F: + Q: etc..

Someone has some idea how to help me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: i see that `I.T Delinquent` has shown you a way to get the local disk letters, so this is an aside ... `Get-ChildItem` is S-L-O-W. it also frequently glitches with long file paths. instead, consider using `robocopy`. not only is it FAST, it handles long paths gracefully. there is a `do nothing` option that you can combine with the log option to get your file list. plus, it works nicely from inside PoSh ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your latest comment, you are using a `foreach` loop without capturing anything, and after that the `Export-Csv` would want to know what it is you are exporting.

If you use a `ForEach-Object` instead of `foreach ($drive in $drives)`, you can use the `$_` automatic variable, PLUS you can pipe the result to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet.

```
# create the CSV filename to output
$outFile = 'C:\{0}_FilesAudit_{1:dd-MM-yyyy}.csv' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, (Get-Date)
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | ForEach-Object {
    # if your PowerShell version is less than 3.0 you'll need
    # Get-ChildItem $_.Root -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
    Get-ChildItem $_.Root -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'FileName'; Expression = {$_.FullName}}   # maybe also select the Length property?
} | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

The `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` lets you continue iterating, even if you do not have permissions on any of the drives/folders, which is often the case on the C: drive.
This means you probably won't get a **complete** listing of all files.

Having said that, are you sure you have permission to write the output CSV file on C: ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
$drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem

foreach ($drive in $drives){
    Get-ChildItem $drive.Root -Recurse
}
```

Let me know how you get on

Comment: I'm use: $drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
$date = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy")
foreach ($drive in $drives){
    Get-ChildItem $drive.Root -Recurse
} Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME'_'FilesAudit'_'$date.csv -NoTypeInformation but the result is: cmdlet Export-Csv at position 1 of the command line
Provide values for the following parameters: